# I get a tensor of 600 values instead of 3 values for mean and std of train_loader in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, mean, normalization, dataloader

I am trying to Normalize my images data and for that I need to find the mean and std for train_loader.

```
mean = 0.0
std = 0.0
nb_samples = 0.0
for data in train_loader:
    images, landmarks = data["image"], data["landmarks"]
    batch_samples = images.size(0)
    images_data = images.view(batch_samples, images.size(1), -1)
    mean +=  torch.Tensor.float(images_data).mean(2).sum(0)
    std += torch.Tensor.float(images_data).std(2).sum(0)
    ###mean += images_data.mean(2).sum(0)
    ###std += images_data.std(2).sum(0)
    nb_samples += batch_samples

mean /= nb_samples
std /= nb_samples
```

the mean and std here are each a torch.Size([600])

When I tried (almost) same code on dataloader, it worked as expected:

```
# code from https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-normalization-using-pre-trained-vgg16-networks/23560/6?u=mona_jalal
mean = 0.0
std = 0.0
nb_samples = 0.0
for data in dataloader:
    images, landmarks = data["image"], data["landmarks"]
    batch_samples = images.size(0)

    images_data = images.view(batch_samples, images.size(1), -1)
    mean += images_data.mean(2).sum(0)
    std += images_data.std(2).sum(0)
    nb_samples += batch_samples

mean /= nb_samples
std /= nb_samples
```

and I got:
`mean is: tensor([0.4192, 0.4195, 0.4195], dtype=torch.float64), std is: tensor([0.1182, 0.1184, 0.1186], dtype=torch.float64)`

So my dataloader is:

```
class MothLandmarksDataset(Dataset):
    """Face Landmarks dataset."""

    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.landmarks_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.landmarks_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()

        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.landmarks_frame.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = io.imread(img_name)
        landmarks = self.landmarks_frame.iloc[idx, 1:]
        landmarks = np.array([landmarks])
        landmarks = landmarks.astype('float').reshape(-1, 2)
        sample = {'image': image, 'landmarks': landmarks}

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample

transformed_dataset = MothLandmarksDataset(csv_file='moth_gt.csv',
                                           root_dir='.',
                                           transform=transforms.Compose(
                                               [
                                               Rescale(256),
                                               RandomCrop(224),
                                               
                                               ToTensor()      
                                               ]
                                                                        )
                                           )



dataloader = DataLoader(transformed_dataset, batch_size=3,
                        shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
```

and train_loader is:

```
# Device configuration
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
seed = 42
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)

# split the dataset into validation and test sets
len_valid_set = int(0.1*len(dataset))
len_train_set = len(dataset) - len_valid_set

print("The length of Train set is {}".format(len_train_set))
print("The length of Test set is {}".format(len_valid_set))

train_dataset , valid_dataset,  = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset , [len_train_set, len_valid_set])

# shuffle and batch the datasets
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

I basically need to get 3 values for mean of train_loader and 3 values for std of train_loader to use as args for Normalize.

images_data in dataloader is torch.Size([3, 3, 50176]) inside the loop and images_data in train_loader is torch.Size([8, 600, 2400])

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, the weird shape you get for your mean and std (`[600]`) is unsuprising, it is due to your data having the shape `[8, 600, 800, 3]`. Basically, the **channel dimension is the last one here**, so when you try to flatten your images with

```
# (N, 600, 800, 3) -> [view] -> (N, 600, 2400 = 800*3)
images_data = images.view(batch_samples, images.size(1), -1)
```

You actually perform a weird operation that fuses together the width and channel dimensions of your image which is now `[8, 600, 2400]`. Thus, applying

```
# (8, 600, 2400) -> [mean(2)] -> (8, 600) -> [sum(0)] -> (600) 
data.mean(2).sum(0)
```

Creates a tensor of size `[600]` which is what you indeed get.

There are two quite simple solutions :
Either you start by [permuting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=permute#torch.Tensor.permute) the dimensions to make the 2nd dimension the channel one :

```
batch_samples = images.size(0)
# (N, H, W, C) -> (N, C, H, W)
reordered = images.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
# flatten image into (N, C, H*W)
images_data = reordered.view(batch_samples, reordered.size(1), -1)
# mean is now (C) = (3)
mean += images_data.mean(2).sum(0)
```

Or you changes the axis along which to apply `mean` and `sum`

```
 batch_samples = images.size(0)
# flatten image into (N, H*W, C), careful this is not what you did
images_data = images.view(batch_samples, -1, images.size(1))
# mean is now (C) = (3)
mean += images_data.mean(1).sum(0)
```

Finally, why did `dataloader`and `trainloader` behave differently ? Well I think it's because one is using `dataset` while the other is using `transformedDataset`. In `TransformedDataset`, you apply the `toTensor`transform which cast a PIL image into a torch tensor, and **I think** that pytorch is smart enough to permute your dimensions during this operation (and put the channels in the second dimension). In other word, your two datasets just do not yield images with identical format, they differ by a permutation of the axis.